# ¿Como puedo hacer que una animación en CSS se quede donde terminó de animar?

Tags: css, css3, animación

Tengo la siguiente animación en CSS para una promoción que debe mostrarse cuando se le pasa el mouse por encima.

```css
.promo {
  position: fixed;
  right: -410px;
  top: 70px;
}
.promo:hover {
  animation-name: stick-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes stick-out {
  from {
    right: -410px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="promo" src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/2qkmhvs.jpg" alt="promo">
```

El problema que tengo es que una vez que la animación termina el logo vuelve a esconderse.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la animación se continúe mostrando donde último se quedó mientras el mouse esté posicionado encima de la imagen usando sólo CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agrégale a `.promo:hover` la declaración:

```
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[El valor forwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) hará que la animación se quede en el estado final en lugar de volver al inicio.

```css
.promo {
  position: fixed;
  right: -410px;
  top: 70px;
}
.promo:hover {
  animation-name: stick-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stick-out {
  from {
    right: -410px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="promo" src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/2qkmhvs.jpg" alt="promo">
```

Comment: Gracias @Carlos Muñoz!

Comment: @Carlos Muñoz muy bueno!!. Estaba intentando que al quitar el hover no se ocultara de golpe pero esta parece ser un poco más complicada y requiere javascript.